# If !empty for multiple lines

Tags: php, html

I have the below PHP function I have tried to put together which I want to show or hide the lines depending on if there is a value assigned to a variable.

```
<?php ( (!empty($_POST['matterNumber']) && !empty($_POST['precedentName']) && !empty($_POST['documentName']) && !empty($_POST['reportName']) && !empty($_POST['stepsforIssue'])) )
{ 
 echo 'Replicating the Issue' . '
 ';

 if(isset($_POST['matterNumber']) && !empty($_POST['matterNumber'])){ 
 echo 'Matter Number                     -    ' . ($_POST['matterNumber']) . '
 '; 
 } 
 if(isset($_POST['precedentName']) && !empty($_POST['precedentName'])){ 
 echo 'Precedent Name                     -    ' . ($_POST['precedentName']) . '
 '; 
 } 
 if(isset($_POST['documentName']) && !empty($_POST['documentName'])){ 
 echo 'Document Name                     -    ' . ($_POST['documentName']) . '
 '; 
 } 
 if(isset($_POST['reportName']) && !empty($_POST['reportName'])){ 
 echo 'Report Name                     -    ' . ($_POST['reportName']) . '
 '; 
 } 
 if(isset($_POST['stepsforIssue']) && !empty($_POST['stepsforIssue'])){ 
 echo 'Steps to replicate/reproduce the issue:' . ($_POST['stepsforIssue']) . '
 '; 
 } 
echo'------------------------------------------------------------------
';
} ?>
```

So for example if all the variables are empty I want nothing to be displayed, although if one or more of the variables are not empty I need the value to be displayed between the title and the hyphens.

### Example

Replicating the issue

Matter Number - 'Value here'

Report Name   - 'Value here'

-----------------------------=

At the moment I am finding the lines stay hidden even if there is a value for one of the variables.

Comment: If you use `!empty` only, it will take care of both `isset` & `!empty`.

Comment: @SougataBose I have made the suggested change but it either leaves all values hidden or if all values are entered they will be shown. If any less than all of the fields have a value then they will all stay hidden.

Comment: You have checked if() twice and you 1st if you have checked if all are not empty then check for others so you have to remove 1st if() conditions for your expected result

Comment: Are you referring to the if() on the first line? because removing this results in `syntax error, unexpected 'echo' (T_ECHO) on line number 3`

Comment: can you please update your code so I can resolve the issue accordingly

Comment: @Sachin I have updated the code to reflect removal of the 1st if() as I understand

Comment: @user10073459 I have posted the answer below, please refer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180418/discussion-between-sachin-and-user10073459).

Comment: @Sachin I have messaged you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a solution to show/hide the area based on another variable as follows, although it isn't the same as the original post it serves the same solution and results in exactly what I need.

```
<?php  if($_POST['closedEscalated'] == 'Escalated'){
echo 'Replicating the Issue' . '
';

 if(isset($_POST['matterNumber']) && !empty($_POST['matterNumber'])){ 
 echo 'Matter Number                     -    ' . ($_POST['matterNumber']) . '
'; 
 } 
 if(isset($_POST['precedentName']) && !empty($_POST['precedentName'])){ 
 echo 'Precedent Name                     -    ' . ($_POST['precedentName']) . '
'; 
 } 
 if(isset($_POST['documentName']) && !empty($_POST['documentName'])){ 
 echo 'Document Name                     -    ' . ($_POST['documentName']) . '
'; 
 } 
 if(isset($_POST['reportName']) && !empty($_POST['reportName'])){ 
 echo 'Report Name                     -    ' . ($_POST['reportName']) . '
'; 
 } 
 if(isset($_POST['stepsforIssue']) && !empty($_POST['stepsforIssue'])){ 
 echo 'Steps to replicate/reproduce the issue:' . ($_POST['stepsforIssue']) . '
'; 
 } 
echo'------------------------------------------------------------------
';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try following

Traversing your `$_POST` array and echo a value which is set.

hope this solve your problem.

```
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
    if(!empty($value))
        echo $key ."=".$value."</br>";
}
```

Comment: I don't quite understand, I have very limited knowledge with PHP, would I use this to replace each of the 'if' statements?

Answer (score 0):

Refer below code for the expected result.

```
 if(!empty($_POST['matterNumber']) || !empty($_POST['precedentName']) || !empty($_POST['documentName']) || !empty($_POST['reportName']) || !empty($_POST['stepsforIssue']))
 { 
   echo 'Replicating the Issue' . '';

   if(isset($_POST['matterNumber']) && !empty($_POST['matterNumber'])){ 
      echo 'Matter Number-'.($_POST['matterNumber']); 
   } 
   if(isset($_POST['precedentName']) && !empty($_POST['precedentName'])){ 
      echo 'Precedent Name -'.($_POST['precedentName']); 
   } 
   if(isset($_POST['documentName']) && !empty($_POST['documentName'])){ 
      echo 'Document Name - '.($_POST['documentName']); 
   } 
   if(isset($_POST['reportName']) && !empty($_POST['reportName'])){ 
      echo 'Report Name - '.($_POST['reportName']); 
   } 
   if(isset($_POST['stepsforIssue']) && !empty($_POST['stepsforIssue'])){ 
      echo 'Steps to replicate/reproduce the issue:'.$_POST['stepsforIssue']; 
   } 
  echo'--------------------------------------------------------------';
 }
```

Comment: This gives an error as follows - FATAL ERROR syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting ',' or ';' on line number 18, although in the meantime I have found the solution. See my answer.

Comment: In line no 18 ")" is extra there without "(" so i have correct it and update the answer

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you're looking for is a shorthand form of your code? And to fix your current display problem change the first line like so

```
 <?php 
   if( isset($_POST['matterNumber']) || isset($_POST['precedentName']) || isset($_POST['documentName']) || isset ($_POST['reportName']) || isset($_POST['stepsforIssue']))
   {

    if( !empty($_POST['matterNumber']) || !empty($_POST['precedentName']) || !empty($_POST['documentName']) || !empty ($_POST['reportName']) || !empty($_POST['stepsforIssue']))
   {
     echo 'Replicating the Issue <br>';

     if(isset($_POST['matterNumber']) && !empty($_POST['matterNumber']))
     { 
       echo " Matter Number: ".$_POST['matterNumber']."<br> ";
     }

     if(isset($_POST['precedentName']) && !empty($_POST['precedentName']))
     {
       echo " Precedent Name: ".$_POST['precedentName']."<br> "; 
     }

     if(isset($_POST['documentName']) && !empty($_POST['documentName']))
     {
       echo " Document Name: ".$_POST['documentName']."<br> ";
     }

     if(isset($_POST['reportName']) && !empty($_POST['reportName']))
     {
       echo " Report Name: ".$_POST['reportName']."<br> ";
     }

     if(isset($_POST['stepsforIssue']) && !empty($_POST['stepsforIssue']))
     { 
      echo " Steps to replicate/reproduce the issue:  ".$_POST['stepsforIssue']."<br> ";
     }
   }
   }
 ?>
```

Also you can use ternary operators to shorten the code further. `||` symbol represents `OR`.

Comment: This results in "FATAL ERROR syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING) on line number 8"

Comment: Oops its a concatenation issue it's fixed now try it.

Comment: So that resolves the error but this still doesn't quite do what I want, I want "Replicating the Issue <br>" to only be echoed if one or more of the below have a value for their variable, else if none of them have  a value I want nothing to be shown, but currently with your answer  "Replicating the Issue <br>" is always displayed.

Comment: Please run `print_r($_POST);` just before the block of code above you will find that one of the variables in the first line is already set hence the block of code will always run.

Comment: Also Try Updated Code